# Smoke simulation is not seen when I activate noise (Blender 2.83)

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm trying to create a smoke simulation, but I'm having problems with the noise, basically until I activate it everything works, but when I go to activate and bake it I don't see anything viewport anymore. Here are my settings:[image]

Comment: Does anything appear on the console window? (go to Window/Toggle System Console to view) Any error messages or anything? It could be that activating the noise is requiring more memory than available and it's failing to bake. Try with significantly lower resolution to try and rule that out (halfing the resolultion will only require 1/8th of the memory for the simulation).

Comment: when noise is enabled, you need to cache/bake the simulation again.

Comment: No - that doesn't work and is not the problem. I am having the same issue. After baking the fluid sim, and THEN baking the noise, the simulation disappears. Turning noise off brings the sim back. After the noise sim is baked, you should be able turn noise on or off. At the moment, noise APPEARS not to be working and might be related to the update to 2.83.4. I'd have to go back to earlier versions to check.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I am having the same problem - noise causing the simulation to disappear altogether after the bake. This seems to be a recent problem so it may be related to the update to 2.83.4. I don't have time to check, but you could try downloading or going back to an earlier version of Blender and seeing if the issue persists there. Please report back to let us know whether that resolved it - then we would know that it was a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bake the noise separately using "Bake Noise".

But I agree that this is weird behavior. Please see my bug report on the topic: [T74526](https://developer.blender.org/T74526)